# The Winter Bash modal window in my profile page is too big

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, winter-bash-2021

The Winter Bash modal window in my profile page is so big that I can't read the buttons at the bottom.  I also can't scroll down to read the buttons.  Is this a bug?

[image: Due to the screen height size, the dialog bottom is cutted off, so it is not possible to read the buttons.]

Comment: what is your screen resolution?

Comment: 1920x1080.  In my image above, I cut out the Windows taskbar at the bottom for privacy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The modal should now have a vertical scrollbar when it is larger than your browser window.

> go check out your hats
> viewport-modal size-mismatch
> now you can go scroll

Comment: good to finally see some haiku's on MSE again

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXyqv.jpg) is how it looks in my mobile. And scrolling scrolls the page in the back

Comment: @SurajRao In your case you dont need to scroll since the modal can fit entirely within your view port (admittedly, not the best smushed-together UI, but should still be functional).