# Cannot scroll in winter bash popup

Tags: bug, design, winter-bash, popups, zoom

I was zooming into my profile picture to get a nice screenshot of my wearing my hat *(to post [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/373010/773001), of course)*, when I ran into a little problem; there is no option for me to scroll anywhere in the winter bash popup, so most of it becomes inaccessible after zooming in.

Here is a GIF to demonstrate:

[image]

Comment: Maybe dupe of https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/373024/347191 ?

Comment: I think that must be browser-related. Can you test in another browser? (Great username, by the way :).

Comment: @SurajRao They're not duplicates, as the post you linked is for where there's no scrollbar, whereas this post is reporting a bug in the scrollbar.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche But yeah, this is status-completed now :)

Comment: I've retracted my flag.  But when you say "this is status-completed now," what do you mean by *this*?  The bug I reported or the bug you are reporting?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche The bug I'm reporting, as it seems that it was browser specific. The scrollbar did work at first, but after me posting, it now does...

Comment: No, wait, now there's *2* scrollbars... I guess I got them confused at first!